# How to create a KeyEvent for control characters un upercase Ctlr+A and lowercase Ctlr+a

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am developing a custom keyboard using xamarin form and I need to create KeyEvent on my custom renderer  for the the Ctrl keys, however I could not find any documentation on how to do it.

I have tried different combination of constructor with the KeyEvent class with no success. For example:

```
webView.DispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEventActions.Down, KeyEvent.KeyCodeFromString(digit), 0, MetaKeyStates .ShiftLeftOn & MetaKeyStates.CtrlLeftOn));
webView.DispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEventActions.Up, KeyEvent.KeyCodeFromString(digit), 0, MetaKeyStates.ShiftLeftOn & MetaKeyStates.CtrlLeftOn));
```

I also tried  the following for lowercase with no success

```
webView.DispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEventActions.Down, KeyEvent.KeyCodeFromString(digit), 0, MetaKeyStates.CtrlLeftOn));
webView.DispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEventActions.Up, KeyEvent.KeyCodeFromString(digit), 0, MetaKeyStates.CtrlLeftOn));
```

This does not provide  the control character I am expecting like Ctrl+C or Ctrl+c.  I am only getting the event for the actual character like c or C but not the control. I am using this code for a WebView  and verifying the  the output with JavaScript. The java script reports correctly the character pressed  but not the Ctrl, even when checking the ctrlKey property of the javaScript event  the flag is set to false.

Comment: Is Keycode.CtrlLeft or Keycode.CtrlRight active ?

Comment: Thats part of the problem, I do not know how to make the ctrl key active